# Tensorflow Object Detection API quantization with output tensor as TFLite_Detection_PostProcess

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, object-detection-api

I am in the process of performing a full 8-bit quantization of [ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz) using Object detection API. For this I run the following [notebook](https://gist.github.com/NobuoTsukamoto/f48df315be490dcf0c76375c2e04ddb1).

In my case my final hardware requires that the output tensors are `TFLite_Detection_PostProcess` (they actually can be float32). However, when performing post-training quantization, with the Object detection API, the final tflite output tensors are `StatefulPartitonedCall`, which are not accepted by the application running on the mcu. So somehow I need to convert to TFLite_Detection_PostProcess.

Some searching reveales that some are using `converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(... output_array=output_array...)` for convertion where they use

```
output_arrays = ['TFLite_Detection_PostProcess', 
           'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1', 
           'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2', 
           'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3']
```

In my case the notebook is using `converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(...)` which does not accept an parameter such as `output_array`.

So, can I quantize using `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model` and define my output tensors to `TFLite_Detection_PostProcess`?

See also TF Object detection API issue tracker [TF2 Detection API Models on mobile TFLite_Detection_PostProcess #10130](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/10130)

Comment: Can you find any solution? I'm working with same problem. thanks

Comment: @CanselOğuz, nope, maybe you can add that you also have this issue at TF2 Detection API Models on mobile TFLite_Detection_PostProcess #10130

Comment: Do you simply need to change the names to TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:x, or is there other changes you need?

Comment: @TaeheeJeong, as far as I know I only need to change from StatefulPartitonedCall to TFLite_Detection_PostProcess.